# SetState inside useEffect causing infite loop after fetching data from firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I am trying to `setEventsList` state to have the `eventList` but I always get an infinite loop. I have successfully gotten the data from firebase as objects and I also want to change the object into an array so that the map function does not throw an error.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { realDB } from '../../firebase/firebase'
import Card from '../events/events'

function CardList(props) {
  const [eventsList, setEventsList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const eventsRef = realDB.ref('/Events').limitToFirst(5);
    eventsRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      var events = snapshot.val();
      let eventList = []
      for (let id in events) {
        eventList.push({
          EventName: events[id].EventName,
          EventEntryFee: events[id].EventEntryFee,
          Eventsport: events[id].Eventsport,
          eventCurrentParticipants: events[id].eventCurrentParticipants,
          EventMaximumParticipants: events[id].EventMaximumParticipants,
          EventTotalPrizes: events[id].EventTotalPrizes,
          EventDifficulty: events[id].EventDifficulty
        });
      }
      setEventsList(eventList);
      console.log(eventsList);
    });
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {eventsList
        ? eventsList.map((event, index) => (
          <Card key={index} />
        )) : (
          <><p> No data</p></>
        )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default CardList;
```

```
// contents of '../../firebase/firebase'

import firebase from "firebase";
import 'firebase/auth'

// Initialize Firebase
const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBxxxxx1wQA",
  authDomain: "fantasxxxxxxxaxxpp.x",
  databaseURL: "https:xxxxxe.x.com",
  projectId: "fxxxxxe",
  storageBucket: "fantxxxm",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
  appId: "1:xxx",
  measurementId: "Gxx-xxxxx"
});

// firebase.analytics();
const db = app.firestore()
const realDB = app.database()
const auth = app.auth()
export { db, auth, realDB }
```

Comment: Does `eventsRef` need to unsubscribe from anything to remove the listener and end state updates?

Comment: I am still new to react. I just want to set the state of  eventsList to the eventList array and map it to the card component. How can I do that without getting an infinite loop with the current code?

Comment: I dont think it should

Comment: Not really sure, the `useEffect` hook only runs once, so either many `onValue` events are occurring, or this `CardList` component is being repeatedly remounted so the effect is running each time. Do you know how often that event is emitted? You can easily test the remounting theory with `useEffect(() => console.log('MOUNTED'), []);` and if you see a bunch then you know it's remounting.

Comment: @DrewReese only once

Comment: Hmm, well then it seems likely it's the `onValue` event handler then. Are you sure you don't need to unsubscribe to any collections or this event listener? Can you shre the `realDB` code in your question so we may see what it does?

Comment: @DrewReese Done. Please check

Comment: @DrewReese still getting an infinite loop even after unsubscribing

Comment: This seems to be an issue with Firebase and not react. If your app isn't re-mounting again, there's no reason for the useEffect to run again. Can you you confirm 2 things - does console outputs eventsList every time during render? Does your parent component render only once (you can check by simply logging from parent component)?

Comment: managed to kinda solve it.Dont know how. Now im getting this error ------Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.------   @AshishGupta

Answer (score 1):

In your current code, there are a number of bugs that could be contributing to the problem.

First, you don't unsubscribe the snapshot listener whenever the component is unmounted. If the parent component removes/readds your `CardList` component, this will cause problems such as updating state out of scope.

You shouldn't use `for (let id in snapshot.val())`, as the ordering from your database query will be discarded. Instead you should use the [`DataSnapshot#forEach`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#foreach) method provided by the Firebase SDK.

I also advise taking care with the Firebase RTDB in regard to differing between a [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) and a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query) as the `DataSnapshot` objects they provide must be consumed in different ways.

When working with arrays in React, you should take care to provide each child element inserted using `map` with a `key` property. In your current code, you make use of the array's index for this but you should use the entry's database key instead so React can efficiently handle the components shuffling around or getting deleted. In a similar vein, your "no data" entry should have a similar key.

You talked about how your `map` function was causing errors if it was set incorrectly, instead of using just `eventsList`, you should also handle the case where your data is still loading. You can either handle this using a type of `Event[] | null` or using a separate `const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)`.

Lastly, you don't have any error handling logic in your code. This could be handled using console logs, but you should set up a `errorMsg` state variable to display a message to the user when something has gone wrong.

So the following changes need to be made:

- Properly unsubscribe the value listener
- Use `DataSnapshot#forEach`
- Rename `eventsRef` to `eventsQuery`
- Rename `snapshot` to `querySnapshot`
- Apply way of handling the loading state.
- Apply error handling.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { realDB } from '../../firebase/firebase'
import Card from '../events/events'

function CardList(props) {
  const [eventsList, setEventsList] = useState(null); // null -> loading
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null); // null -> no error

  useEffect(() => {
    const eventsQuery = realDB.ref('/Events').limitToFirst(5);

    const valueListener = eventsQuery.on(
      'value',
      (querySnapshot) => {
        const eventList = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(eventSnapshot => {
          const eventData = eventSnapshot.val();
          eventList.push({
            _key: eventSnapshot.key;
            EventName: eventData.EventName,
            EventEntryFee: eventData.EventEntryFee,
            Eventsport: eventData.Eventsport,
            eventCurrentParticipants: eventData.eventCurrentParticipants,
            EventMaximumParticipants: eventData.EventMaximumParticipants,
            EventTotalPrizes: eventData.EventTotalPrizes,
            EventDifficulty: eventData.EventDifficulty
          });
        }
        console.log("refreshing eventsList", eventsList);
        setEventsList(eventList);
        setErrorMsg(null);
      },
      (error) => {
        setEventsList([]);
        setErrorMsg("Something went wrong.");
      }
    );

    return () => eventsQuery.off('value', valueListener);
  }, []);

  if (eventsList === null) {   // is loading?
    return (<div><key="loading"><p>loading...</p></></div>);
  }

  if (errorMsg !== null) {     // has error?
    return (<div><key="error"><p>{errorMsg}</p></></div>);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      { eventsList.length > 0
        ? eventsList.map((event) => (
          <Card key={event._key} />
        )) : (
          <key="nodata"><p>No data</p></>
        )
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default CardList;
```

If the error persists, you'll need to look at the parent component and see if it is rerendering rapidly.

**Side Note:** `eventCurrentParticipants` should be renamed `EventCurrentParticipants` and `Eventsport` as `EventSport` to be consistent with the rest of your data. Although, using `Event` at the start of each property is also superfluous.